# Is it necessary creating a function in model when updating database

Tags: php

I have a controller like this

```
use App\Model\User;
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    protected $model;
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->model = $user;
    }
    public function updatePhone(Request $request)
    {
        //user id
        $id = $request->id;
        //new phone number
        $phone = $request->phone;
    }
}
```

The function updatePhone is used to update the phone number of the user.So I can code like this

```
$res = $this->model->where('id',$id)->update('phone',$phone)
```

In this way, I do nothing in the user model.But I get used to like this

```
$res = $this->model->updatePhone($id, $phone);
```

And I must create function updatePhone in user model

```
public function updatePhone($id,$phone)
{
    return $this->where('id',$id)->update('phone',$phone);
}
```

who is the better way to update a single model? Any answers or suggestions are excepted.